# symfony's paramconverter equivalent in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm pretty new in .Net community, please show mercy haha. I got **two questions**:

1. is there any similar implementation of [symfony's `@paramconverter`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) annotation in ASP.NET (such as a converter attributes)?
   e.g. the request url, no matter GET/POST/PUT/DELETE, the api request with an `id` of certain entity and we are able to convert/bind such id into a entity object(say `productId` in int and convert to `Product` object)

Expected PseudoCode:

```
[Route("products/{productId}/comments")]
[ProductConverter]
public HttpResponseMessage getProductComments(Product product) {
    // product here not only with `productId` field, but already converted/bind into `Product`, through repository/data store
    ....
}
```

2. Is this good practise in .Net? I ask for this implementation because I think this pattern able to reduce duplicate code as API requests mainly rely on object `id`. I can even throw an exception if such `Product` object not found by such string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ModelBinder is equiuvalent to symphony's parmconverter. You can read more about it here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Here is sample:

First you have to implement IModelBinder. That's very basic implementation of it:

```
public class ProductBinder : IModelBinder
{

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(Product))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var id = (int)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("productId").ConvertTo(typeof(int));

        // Create instance of your object
        bindingContext.Model = new Product { Id = id };
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next you have to configure ASP.NET WebApi to use that binder. In WebApiConfig.cs file (or any other where you configure WebAPI) add the following line:

```
config.BindParameter(typeof(Product), new ProductBinder());
```

The final step is to create correct controller method. It's important to provide correct route parameter in order to correct binding.

```
[Route("products/{productId}/comments")]
public HttpResponseMessage getProductComments(Product product) {

}
```

I don't think that this is bad practice or good practices. As always it depends. For sure it reduce code duplication and introduce some order to your code. If the object with that `id` doesn't exists you can even try tweak this binder to return response 404 (not found)

**Edit:**

Using `IModelBinder` with dependency injection is a bit tricky but still possible. You have to write additional extension method:

```
public static void BindParameter(this HttpConfiguration config, Type type, Type binderType)
{
    config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, new SimpleModelBinderProvider(type, () => (IModelBinder)config.DependencyResolver.GetService(binderType)));
    config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, type, param => param.BindWithModelBinding());
}
```

It's based on orginal method found [there](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs). The only difference is that it expect type of the binder instead of instance. So you just call:

```
config.BindParameter(typeof(Product), typeof(ProductBinder));
```

Comment: Your answer looks good but not work for me. When getting the object with repository (or dealing with dependency injection of services), using these approach can't keep the services (I'm using Ninject, may be the binder cannot be kept in the RequestScope).

Comment: @chakming I've updated my answer with description how to manage IModelBinder with dependency injection